# WPF DataBinding from class (Expression Blend)

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

Hi i have a class called GameEngine.cs

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GameEnginee
{
public class GameEngine
{
    private int life;

    public String Life { get { return life.ToString(); } }

    public GameEngine(int life)
    {
        this.life = life;
    }

}
}
```

1)I used expression blend and added the GameEngine.cs to solution explorer and clicked "build project".

2) Then under the "Data" tab, there is "Create Sample Data" OR "Create Data Souce". I first tried create data source but i cant find gameengine. Then i tried Create Sample Data and i could find game engine.

3) So i "Create Sample data" -> From class -> And i chose Game engine.

Then i inserted a textbox and bound it to DataContext of GameEngine.Life

When i run project nothing is appearing in the textbox.

So i tried inserting an event handler whenGridLoaded in which i initialized a new instance of game.
GameEngine game = new GameEngine(100);

I Expected the 100 to appear in the textBox but nothing happened.

**EDIT**

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

namespace GameEnginee
{

public class GameEngine : INotifyPropertyChanged

```
{

    private int life;


    public int Life
    {
        get
        {
            return life;
        }
    }

    public GameEngine(int life)
    {
        this.life = life;
    }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Life");
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is the textblock in the main window?  When is the game engine object created in relation to when the textblock is created?

Comment: If the game engine is created after the textblock, the life value won't get pushed to the textblock, because you're not using a dependency property.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `GameEngin` class and follow this [article](http://wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html).

According to above article (`INotifyPropertyChanged`) you must have `OnProperyChanged("Life")` in the `Set` part of your `Life` property. it can inform about changes of this property to your `UI`.

For example test something like this:

```
public class GameEngin:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _life;

    public int Life
    {
        get
        {
            return _life;
        }
        set
        {
            _life = value;
            OnProperyChanged("Life")
        }
    }

    public GameEngine()
    {
        this.Life = 3; // For Test
    }


    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnProperyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            var handler= PropertyChanged ;
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hI I edited it. the problem is after i compile its not appearing in "Create Data Source" under Data Tab but only appears in "Create Sample Data Source". After i bind using Sample Data Source a random number appears in textbox. But when i compile and run it nothing appears in the textbox

Comment: Try the sample class in my answer.